# Help decoding resonator/oscillator marking

Tags: frequency, surface-mount, markings

I'm looking at a PCB for a car remote (either 314.xx or 433.xx MHz), and the resonator or oscillator (SMD, crystal? ceramic?, Japanese?) has following markings:

```
0300
T 7205
```

What frequency could it be, and how to decode these markings in general?

[image]

Comment: Picture please.

Comment: It's too small to see the markings, but sure I'll add an overall pic

Comment: What's the other side of the board? It doesn't look like there are any RF components on that side.  What car is it for? What country?

Comment: The other side only has a battery. The antenna is the trace on the perimeter of the board. It's a Denso remote (toyota, lexus, etc.) which is available in multiple regions in different frequencies. It could be aftermarket though...

Comment: Seems pins close to the edge of the board are not connected, and two traces go to the chip, thus I think it is automotive resonator. 7205 might be a date code, thus value is most probably "0300". Time to examine board again to see if my guesses have base and use scope to see the frequency.

Comment: @Anonymous how would read `7205` if it were a date code?

Comment: @qarma people who do not know the answer usually say *This is a very good question!* 05 may be the year, 72 can not be week number in the year, may be a week number after production start. Anyway wrong guess is usually better than no guess at all, the only thing is needed now is to test hypothesis with frequency.

Comment: I've learnt that emitted frequency is 433/434MHz, the oscillator frequency may be a fraction of that if the main IC has a PLL.